# error: template is declared here. class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_stringstream;

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

I am writing a c++ program to find the number of words in a string using stringstream in c++ but my compiler is giving the above error.
I am using vsCode on my macbook air to do this and using the Xcode's GNU compiler.
I also tried to write the code in the CLION ide which also gives the same error.
Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int countWords(string str) 
{ 
    // breaking input into word using string stream 
    stringstream s(str); // Used for breaking words 
    string word; // to store individual words 

    int count = 0; 
    while (s >> word) 
        count++; 
    return count; 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    string s = "using stringstream class in cplusplus";
    cout << " Number of words are: " << countWords(s); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Add `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: yaa thanks @songyuanyao it worked immediately after adding sstream.